# Share Widget is appearing twice in Action Bar when creating a simple Android App

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, share

Share Intent is inflated only once in DefaultActivityFragment but it is appearing twice on Activity.

![Screen with two share buttons]

DetailActivityFragment.java is shown below

```
                public class DetailActivityFragment extends Fragment {

                public static final String LOG_TAG = DetailActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();
                public static final String FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG = " #SunshineApp";
                private String mForecastStr;

                public DetailActivityFragment() {
                    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

                    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                    if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
                        mForecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text)).setText(mForecastStr);
                    }
                    return rootView;
                }

                public Intent createShareForecastIntent() {
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mForecastStr + FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG);
                    return shareIntent;
                }

                @Override
                public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.detailfragement, menu);

                    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
                    ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
                    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
                        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
                    } else {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Share Action Provider is null?");
                    }
                    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
                }
            }strong text
```

DetActivity.java can be seen here:

```
            public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
                    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.container, new DetailActivityFragment())
                                .commit();
                    }
                    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                    setupActionBar();
                }

                /**
                 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
                 */
                private void setupActionBar() {
                    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                    if (actionBar != null) {
                        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
                        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                    int id = item.getItemId();

                    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
                    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class));
                        return true;
                    }

                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }

            }
```

Also both menu files - detailframent.xml:

```
            <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.DetailActivityFragment">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_share"
                    android:title="@string/action_share"
                    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
                    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
            </menu>
```

and detail.xml is also pasted:

```
            <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.DetailActivity">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
                    android:orderInCategory="100"
                    android:title="@string/action_settings"
                    app:showAsAction="never" />
            </menu>
```

I am not able to understand why it is appearing twice? Also why whatsapp symbol is been shown there. I agree I have selected that but in other apps we use the selection does not retain itself on the screen. how to remove that?